# Removing and adding keys while looping through a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a dictionary and I want to remove a key from the dict and change it to something else. However, when I loop through the dictionary something strange happens to the final key that I do not understand.

Here I am printing the keys before and after removing a key and adding a new one in its place

```
from operator import add

x = {(19,2):0, (1,1):1, (10,1):2, (5,5):3}
y = (1, 0)

for i in x.values():

    newDir = tuple(map(add, x.keys()[i], y))
    print x.keys()[i]
    x.pop( x.keys()[i] )
    x[newDir] = i

    print x.keys()[i]
    print i
    print ' '
```

This produces the following:

```
(19, 2)
(20, 2)
0

(1, 1)
(2, 1)
1

(10, 1)
(2, 1)
2

(11, 1)
(2, 1)
3
```

Notice how the key of value 3 is not `(5,5)` but `(11,1)` and after popping out and adding a new key it should have been `(6,5)` and not `(2,1)`. I do not know where `(11,1)` is coming from and why `(2,1)` is repeating in value 2 and 3.

The correct output would be

```
(19, 2)
(20, 2)
0

(1, 1)
(2, 1)
1

(10, 1)
(11, 1)
2

(5, 5)
(6, 5)
3
```

Comment: I'm trying to add (1,0) (i.e. y) to each key in the dictionary. Because dictionary is immutable, I am trying to remove each time, change it, and place it back in with the same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered and their apparent order may change whenever you add/remove a key. That means that `x.keys()[i]` is not guaranteed to give you the correct key (at least after you have altered `x` by adding or removing keys). Because after you pop and add a new key the order may have changed and that means `x.keys()[i]` **may give any** key from the dictionary.

For example in your output it

- worked for the first one: `(19, 2)` -> `(20, 2)`.
- It also worked for the second one: `(1, 1)` -> `(2, 1)`.
- It started failing for the third one: `(10, 1)` -> `(2, 1)`! The correct key was found and modified but the "apparent" result was the result of value `1`!
- For the fourth one everything broke: `(11, 1)` is the key of value `2` after it has been changed and the apparent result is the key for value `1`.

So instead of changing it in-place you should create a new dictionary:

```
from operator import add

x = {(19,2):0, (1,1):1, (10,1):2, (5,5):3}
y = (1, 0)
newx = {}

for key, value in x.items():
    print(key)

    newDir = tuple(map(add, key, y))
    newx[newDir] = value

    print(newDir)
    print(value)
    print(' ')

print(newx)
```

which produces the expected output:

```
(19, 2)
(20, 2)
0

(1, 1)
(2, 1)
1

(10, 1)
(11, 1)
2

(5, 5)
(6, 5)
3

{(20, 2): 0, (11, 1): 2, (6, 5): 3, (2, 1): 1}
```